# Javascript security, calling functions after action

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

This is more "thinker" than problem. 
I have a problem with thinking about how to secure javacript.

Let's say I have this setup:

```
Main page with iframe in it
Iframe with content.
```

Now, Let's say, user has to play a game in the iframe. After he finishes the game the iframe calls:

```
window.parent.givePrice();
```

The parent will show modal window:

```
function givePrice(){
  jQuery('.mask').show();
  jQuery('#won').show();
}
```

In this modal window they will have something like

```
Congratulations! you just won a brand new BMW! Click Here to get your price
```

And after he clicks on the link, his name gets signed (by ajax - not relevant) into Database table "winners".

(Please remember, this is just an example).

Now This all sounds great, but I can see so many security holes in this. For example if I use firebug and write "givePrice();" it shows me directly the modal that I won, even though I didn't touch the game at all.

Can someone discuss, what would be the best way to secure example like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to prevent someone cheating is to have the action of making a guess (or whatever it is that lets them "win") be a round-trip to the server:

1. Trigger the attempt-to-win (e.g., the user clicks something, or guesses, or whatever it is).
2. Your page sends the information (including username) to the server.
3. Server does several things:

   1. Checks rate-limiting related to that account and IP address. (So the user can't just create a script that tries to win every second for a month, etc.)
   2. Checks the guess or whatever.
   3. If the stars align, records that that user "won".
4. Show response to the user.

If you want to make winning and accepting the win separate steps, you'd do that with another round-trip. On the first trip, the server generates a unique acceptance code and records that the user won and what their acceptance code is on the server. On the second trip, which involves the page sending back the code, checks the code (and several other fraud checks) and records the user accepted.

There's no secure way to do this client-side-only. Remember you can't trust **anything** sent from the client.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer! Yes the loop back to the server make sense, the problem is that not always it is a "answer". Sometimes its just a boolean value. Like in this case "Won"/"Lost". Lets say the game is a airplane which needs to shoot 5 other airplanes. Pretty straight forward, and only way out is to shoot the others. What do you check on the server side then?

Comment: No worries. *"The only way to prevent someone cheating..."* Really I should have said "The only way to *minimize* cheating..." Even with rate-limiting by IP and user account, a sufficiently-motivated person will find a way to cheat; it just raises the bar a fair bit. (And winning a brand-new BMW would qualify as sufficient motivation, for a lot of people!) Not to sound pessimistic or anything... ;-) So you'll have to be sure to double-check things manually once a prize has been awarded (and word your terms and conditions clearly; e.g., you get to decide whether there was fraud). Best,

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it was only example, the real purpose is much more dynamic, and basically it is impossible to hand-check all prize assignment as there will be a lot of them, different people, different prizes. To my previous comment, with boolean "won" / "lost", it might work that i would add to the game its own "won key" and the game would send that, probably?

Comment: Re your airplane example: Ugh, making it difficult to cheat at that will be a hassle. If the hitting airplanes is really just a token thing (you're not really trying to make it a precondition), you could tally it client-side and just accept that someone will hack it. If it's really meant to be a precondition, that's a **lot** harder. You'd almost have to continually send a stream of data to the server and make the server decide whether the hit was real. (You might duplicate that check client-side for responsiveness, but the server would have to be the final arbiter).

Comment: Ah hehe no, I dont go that deap :) If they shoot the airplanes by real gun I dont care :) Actually the game would not come from me at all, it would be developmed by other people. Therefore, if they cheat inside of the game, its not my problem. My concern is, not to let them win the prize if they didn't finish / win the game. If they win the game by cheating is not my problem. Make more sense?

Comment: :-) In that case, some kind of game-specific code, sent to the server when they "win" along with their username, with rate-limiting server-side by user account and IP address should do the trick reasonably well.

Comment: Ok, got the general idea and going to play with it now. Basically what I will do is to generate a instance key on parent backend, store this key in DB, pass this key to iframe (First I thought just by $_GET, but as I see it as security risk as well, I think I will use $_SESSION), application runs in iframe, after finishing, application calls script "User x finished instance x", this will change status of instance in Datbase, then application call parent.gameWon();, function gameWon(); will check database if current user has instance x with right status and if yes, it will show "Congrats!"

Answer (score 0):

I'd say not to do it trough pure JavaScript and use some checks on server side. You can always break trough any Javascript protection using Firebug or any other similar tool. Even via firing requests directly to server and sending fake data.

So IMO all check should be done on server side: whether user opened game, then from game send data that he actually played etc.